# Join query is not working properly in laravel 4.2

Tags: jquery, join, laravel, left-join

I am using laravel 4.2. When I run this `Left Join` query,

```
$data = DB::table('posts')
        -> leftJoin('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
        -> where('posts.id',$id)
        -> select('posts.id as post_id,posts.title as title,users.firstname as fname')
        -> first();
```

When I print the `$data` got the result,

```
stdClass Object(
   [post_id,posts.title] => 5
)
```

This is not the expected answer. I expect the answer like,

```
stdClass Object(
  [post_id] => 2
  [title] => Test3
  [fname] => myname
)
```

How can I get the correct result? Is there anything wrong with this query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the select

```
  $data = DB::table('posts')
            -> leftJoin('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
            -> where('posts.id',$id)
            -> select('posts.id as post_id','posts.title as title','users.firstname as fname')
            -> first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('posts')
    -> select('posts.id,users.id,posts.title users.firstname')
    -> leftJoin('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
    -> where('posts.id',$id)
    -> first();
```

this should give you appropriate result